# How to use native Textview (View) in Andengine Game Activity

Tags: android, textview, arabic, andengine

I want to know is there any way to use native `TextView` or any other layout of android inside BaseAndEngine `Activity`.

My application is using Andengine for one of its whole screen. This screen is extended from BaseAndEngine and I need to use some native view like textview inside that screen. Because Andengine does not work fine for Arabic text and I need to show some Arabic text on gaming screen.

OR if possible how to show Arabic text in changeable text in Andengine. As changeable text write Arabic from left to right in reverse order.

Comment: Hello, did u solve the problem of showing Arabic in changeable Text in andengine? i face same problem now. could u help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can.

Check this code out - basically you override `onSetContentView`, then you can set whatever you want.

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
    final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameLayoutLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);
    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams surfaceViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(super.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
    frameLayout.addView(this.mRenderSurfaceView, surfaceViewLayoutParams);

    //Create any other views you want here, and add them to the frameLayout.

    this.setContentView(frameLayout, frameLayoutLayoutParams);
}
```

(This method goes to your subclass of `BaseGameActivity`.)

You could also do it through xml, but I think this method is more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it looks possible and straight forward. I would try this and will let you know.

Comment: This answer does not show how to use a TextView IN Andengine so much as how to display one OVER Andengine. @Rai could clarify they do not need to integrate the TextView with Andengine.

Comment: True, android views can't be used inside the game, but this is the closest solution. Anyway, @Rai you could add your own Arabic font to your project, then I guess you'll be able to use Arabic letters in AndEngine.

Comment: I tried this and works well with getting a native button on screen. Now I'm stuck with the positioning of the button wrt the camera. I want it to exactly align its top with a sprite on the camera? I tried setting the padding but with change in screen size it gets haphazard. Detailed Explanation here : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29926903/andengine-camera-and-device-display-ratio-between-co-ordinates-on-each)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Andengine for Arabic and Persian fonts too. But in a different manner. to do that you need to create a Sprite and add a bitmap to it. before that you draw your text on that bitmap.

the following code is an example that draw the Persian/Arabians text and attach it to a sprite. so we can attach the sprite to our scene.
this is an example to show how we can do that, so you can adjust the bitmap and text size by yourself.
if your device support Persian/Arabians, this code will work properly. if the text does not appear in your scene, change its position, it is out of screen

the example code function will print the "Persian Golf" in Persian/Arabians.

```
private void persianGolfPrinter(){
            BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(ResourceManager.getInstance().gameActivity.getTextureManager(), 400, 800, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
            ITextureRegion mDecoratedBalloonTextureRegion;
            final IBitmapTextureAtlasSource baseTextureSource = new EmptyBitmapTextureAtlasSource(400, 800);
            final IBitmapTextureAtlasSource decoratedTextureAtlasSource = new BaseBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator(baseTextureSource) {
                    @Override
                    protected void onDecorateBitmap(Canvas pCanvas) throws Exception {
                            this.mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                            this.mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
                            this.mPaint.setTextSize(32f);
                            this.mPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
                            pCanvas.drawText("خلیج فارس", 150, 150, this.mPaint);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public BaseBitmapTextureAtlasSourceDecorator deepCopy() {
                            throw new DeepCopyNotSupportedException();
                    }
            };

            mDecoratedBalloonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(mBitmapTextureAtlas, decoratedTextureAtlasSource, 0, 0);
            mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();

            Sprite test = new Sprite(0,0,mDecoratedBalloonTextureRegion,ResourceManager.getInstance().engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
            this.attachChild(test);
    }
```

don't use android textview... it makes your game ugly ....

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use them directly in AndEngine, because the objects in Andengine are OpenGL objects. But you can use android OS to draw a bitmap of any standard view, and then create a texture and a sprite from that view. This is less than optimum for a case such as arabic text, but it will work. Be careful about memory leaks as you create the bitmaps of your views.